# Inequality in Hilbert modules

Tags: hilbert-modules

I am going through the book 'K-Theory and C^*-algebras' by Wegge-Olsen and at the moment I don't see why would a certain inequality hold. It is below underlined with red.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy, but maybe different order of (in)equalities:
\begin{align*}
\Vert xa \Vert^2 &= \Vert a^* (x|x) a \Vert\\
&\leq \Vert a^* \Vert \Vert (x|x) \Vert \Vert a \Vert = \Vert a^* \Vert \Vert x \Vert^2 \Vert a \Vert\\
&= \Vert a \Vert^2 \Vert x \Vert^2
\end{align*}